# How to call MS Graph API in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, nuget, asp.net-core-webapi

**Scenario**

My project consists of two applications:

- Frontend: Angular with msal-angular to authenticate users to Azure AD
- Backend: ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

**Purpose of application**

User can set a new pin to access company workplace

**Security problem**

If user1 knows the `employeeId` of user2, user1 can retrieve and also change the pin of user2

**Idea to fix the issue**

Calling MS GRaph API from backend.

Implementing auth in backend to retrieve employeeId of requesting user => comparing employeeId in request with actual employeeId of user

This is my code:

`program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var MyConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(graphBaseUrl: "https://graph.microsoft.com", defaultScopes: "User.Read") // Änderung hier
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(builder =>
                    builder.WithOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200",
                        "https://app-gws-pinguin.azurewebsites.net")
                    .AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().WithMethods("GET", "DELETE", "POST", "PUT"));

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(
    c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "PINguin API");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    }
    );

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

`KeyVaultController.cs` file:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource;
using pinguin_api.Models;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace pinguin_api.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    [Route("api/KeyVault")]
    [ApiController]
    public class KeyVaultController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SecretClient _secretClient;
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public KeyVaultController(IConfiguration configuration, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            var keyVaultUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUrl");
            _secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        [HttpGet("getSecret")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSecret([FromQuery] string secretName)
        {
            try
            {
                // Benutzeridentität aus dem Access Token extrahieren
                var userId = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId))
                {
                    return Unauthorized("User identity could not be verified.");
                }

                // Personalnummer des Benutzers aus Azure AD abrufen
                var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();
                var employeeId = user.OnPremisesExtensionAttributes.ExtensionAttribute1;
                var userEmployeeNumber = user.AdditionalData["extensionAttribute1"].ToString();

                // Überprüfen, ob die Personalnummer übereinstimmt
                if (secretName != userEmployeeNumber)
                {
                    return Unauthorized("The employee number does not match the authenticated user.");
                }

                // Geheimnis aus KeyVault abrufen
                KeyVaultSecret secret = await _secretClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

                if (secret != null)
                {
                    return Ok(secret.Value);
                }

                return NotFound();
            }
            catch (ServiceException e) when (e.InnerException is UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                return Unauthorized($"Error accessing user data: {e.Message}");
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                return BadRequest(); // 400 Bad Request
            }
            catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
            {
                return StatusCode(403); // 403 Forbidden
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("setSecret")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SetSecret(SecretModel secretModel)
        {
            if (secretModel == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secretModel.SecretName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secretModel.SecretValue))
            {
                return BadRequest("Secret name and value are required.");
            }

            try
            {
                KeyVaultSecret secret = new KeyVaultSecret(secretModel.SecretName, secretModel.SecretValue);
                secret.Properties.Tags.Add("EmployeeName", secretModel.SecretTag);
                await _secretClient.SetSecretAsync(secret);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Azure.RequestFailedException e)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Error setting secret: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-pinguin_api-922cbc86-144d-48ee-a4a5-05baafcbc41b</UserSecretsId>
    <RootNamespace>pinguin_api</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.36.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**What I tried**

[A web API that calls web APIs: Call an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-web-api-call-api-call-api?tabs=aspnetcore)

[A web API that calls web APIs: Code configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-web-api-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#option-1-call-microsoft-graph)

**Error**

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProviderOption' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>
> at Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.b__1_0(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method11(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

### Update 07.12.2023:

#### Removing all Graph associated code from `KeyVaultController.cs`

In my `KeyVaultController.cs` I removed all of the code related to the `GraphServiceCLient`.
I've requested the same endpoint for `GetSecret` again and I got `no errors`.

#### Only having declaration and initialization of Graph inside `KeyVaultController.cs`

In my `KeyVaultController.cs` I removed most of the code related to the `GraphServiceClient`. However I left the declaration and initialization in the constructor to check, if it works now.
After requesting the endpoint again for `GetSecret` I got the `same exact error` as mentioned above.

**Conclusion**:
It looks like the problem persists in the following lines of code:

```
private readonly SecretClient _secretClient;
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public KeyVaultController(IConfiguration configuration, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            var keyVaultUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUrl");
            _secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }
```

### Update and problem solved 14.12.2023:

Thanks for the support in the comments.
I didn't now fix the error, but I managed to solve my problem using the `httpclient`.
I had a very specific task to fetch not only user information, but specifically an extensionAttribute which was created for a user in Azure AD. The code still works for other requests to the MSGraph as well.

```
private readonly SecretClient _secretClient;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public KeyVaultController(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            var keyVaultUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultUrl");
            _secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
        }

        private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            string authority = $"{_configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{_configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";

            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"])
                        .WithClientSecret(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
                        .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                        .Build();

            var result = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        private async Task<JsonElement> GetUserFromGraphAsync(string userEmail, string accessToken)
        {
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(userPrincipalName,'{userEmail}')&$select=displayName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes";

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonResponse);
            var userElement = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("value")[0].Clone(); // Klonen des Elements
            return userElement;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Maido47, please share your `.csproj` file  ？

Comment: @JasonPan thanks for the reply. Just added my  `.csproj` code

Comment: I just added an Update to my Question regarding the implementation of the `GraphServiceClient`

Comment: Maybe a stupid question. The code above seems to be using Azure Key Vault service. Do you have it? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/key-vault

Comment: Seems this package is missing `` Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient`` based on those urls mentioned.